# How to set `cmp-zsh` completion source for `:!` commands (`nvim-cmp` stuff)?

Tags: neovim, lua, nvim-cmp, cmp-zsh

I have next setup for `nvim-cmp` cmdline `:` completion:

```
cmp.setup.cmdline(':', {
    mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.cmdline(),
    sources = cmp.config.sources({
        -- { name = 'path' },
        { name = 'zsh' },
    }, {
        {
            name = 'cmdline',
            option = {
                ignore_cmds = { 'Man', '!' }
            }
        }
    })
})
```

It uses `zsh` completion for paths and `!` command, and `cmdline` completion for
vim `:` stuff.

How it started: I have been using `path` and `cmdline` completion at the start of my journey, but I quickly found out that when I try to `:!mv ~/Downdloads/file with spaces.txt ./file.txt` I get no space escaping (`file\ with\ spaces.txt`) from `path`. So I added the `cmp-zsh` plugin. In the current setup with `zsh` completion source I have next problems:

- When I am writing some `:` commands I get the `zsh` and `path` completion. I want to get only `path`
- When I am writing some `:!<command>` commands, I get no completion for `<command>` because no shell commands start from `!`.

***SO there is the question: How to make the `zsh` source be accessible only within `:!<command> ...` and disable `path` for `:`?*** As You may have noticed, I have already disabled `cmdline` for `:!` commands.

The `:h nvim-cmp` does not contain definition for `:!` mode. Actually, it says:

> ```
> *cmp.setup.cmdline* (cmdtype: string, config: cmp.ConfigSchema)
>  Setup cmdline configuration for the specific type of command.
>  See |getcmdtype()|.
>  NOTE: nvim-cmp does not support the `=` command type.
> ```

So, there is the `getcmdtype()` definition:

> ```
> getcmdtype()                       *getcmdtype()*
>       Return the current command-line type. Possible return values
>       are:
>           :   normal Ex command
>           >   debug mode command |debug-mode|
>           /   forward search command
>           ?   backward search command
>           @   |input()| command
>           -   |:insert| or |:append| command
>           =   |i_CTRL-R_=|
>       Only works when editing the command line, thus requires use of
>       |c_CTRL-\_e| or |c_CTRL-R_=| or an expression mapping.
>       Returns an empty string otherwise.
>       Also see |getcmdpos()|, |setcmdpos()| and |getcmdline()|.
> ```

It looks like there is no `:!` mode. Then how I can solve the

> *SO there is the question: How to make the `zsh` source be accessible only within `:!<command> ...` and disable `path` for `:`?*

problem...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partially solved with

```lua
            cmp.setup.cmdline({ '/', '?' }, {
                mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.cmdline(),
                sources = {
                    { name = 'buffer' }
                }
            })

            cmp.setup.cmdline(':', {
                mapping = cmp.mapping.preset.cmdline(),
                sources = cmp.config.sources({
                    -- { name = 'path' },
                    {
                        name = 'cmdline',
                        group_index = 1,
                        option = {
                            ignore_cmds = { 'Man', '!' }
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        name = 'zsh',
                        group_index = 2,
                    },
                })
            })
```